# Is it possible to tweak Steam's download bandwith limit settings?

Tags: windows, steam

In **Settings > Downloads > Download Restrictions**, we can limit the download bandwidth to one of a number of predefined speeds. Is it possible to set arbitrary values (for example, in some file) to better match our connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way I've come across whilst googling for this myself. It involves editing steam's config file.  
Here's the solution, taken from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/3vvizg/setting_custom_download_speed_limit/):

> For those who want to set a custom download speed limit, to download a
>   game and do whatever else on your computer here is how you do it.
>   Close Steam before doing this or it won't work.
>
> 1. Go into your Steam directory, under this directory open the config directory. (Commonly `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\config`)
> 2. Go into the config directory and edit the `config.vdf` file.
> 3. Find the "DownloadThrottleKbps" and set it to the desired speed. (Take the number you want, so 2.7 MB/s in my case, multiply by 8000 to
>      get 21600)
> 4. Save the file and open steam, verify that it is working.